# AWS ATHENA has invalid data type: STRUCT

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, parquet, amazon-athena

I'm trying to create a table in AWS Glue catalog based on a parquet file stored in S3. Parquet file has nested struct field that contains multiple fields and opens in any parquet viewer just fine.

That's how I define tabe if I use Hive directly (and it works):

```
CREATE TABLE hive.testtable (  
  testrecord ROW(field1 VARCHAR,
  field2 VARCHAR)
)
WITH (
  format = 'PARQUET'
);
```

That's how I declare column in AWS Glue for testrecord column:

```
STRUCT <  
  field1: STRING,
  field2: STRING
>
```

However, when I perform a query against a table registered in AWS Glue I receiver the error:
"HIVE_INVALID_METADATA: Glue table 'testtable' column 'testrecord' has invalid data type: STRUCT

Not sure at all what can be the issue.

Any advice appreciated.

**UPDATE**
This happens only when table is created in Aws Glue. If I create table using explicit "create table.." in Athena query editor - everything is ok.